# what is void* in the explicit cast operator and what is use of it?

Tags: c#

I just came across below code in mscorlib `IntPtr` structure while pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in visual studio.

```
public static unsafe explicit operator void* (IntPtr value)
{
    return value.m_value;
}
```

I do know that we can define explicit cast operator like this but it is void* so I am confused what is this and what is use of that?

Comment: That would be a void pointer

Comment: I think this article has a good https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

Comment: more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb(VS.80).aspx

Comment: It represents a pointer to an unknown type. This means that you do not know the size of the thing it points to. A void* in C# is almost always only used when interoperating with unmanaged code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Void* is a void pointer. It is a construct that is often used in C++. Most of the times it is used when you want to use a pointer for either a multiple other data types or if you are not sure what datatype you will use the pointer for.

In essence you can see it as sort of a generic as it can be cast to any other pointer type and vice versa. It is usually used when dealing with unmanaged code and is a C++ construct.  In managed code it normally finds no usage.